Apache reverse proxy to kibana dashboard with anonymous authentication redirects to login
I have a Kibana server where anonymous authentication is enabled.
Inside this server I built a dashboard which I want to be accessible by everyone. This dashboard is inside a space where only kibana anonymous user has permissions.
To ease access to the site, I put an Apache beforehand, and I made a reverse proxy to this dashboard's public URL.
This is my proxy code:
<Location /city>
  ProxyPass https://my-kibana-domain:5601/complete-url-to-public-dashboard
  ProxyPassReverse https://my-kibana-domain:5601/complete-url-to-public-dashboard
</Location>

ProxyPass / https://my-kibana-domain:5601/
ProxyPassReverse / https://my-kibana-domain:5601/

I'm not using a basePath inside my kibana configuration.
If I try https://my-kibana-domain:5601/complete-url-to-public-dashboard on a browser, the dashboard is reached without asking for authentication.
If I try https://my-kibana-domain/city I'm redirected to login page, and after selecting anonymous access I got an error stating that dashboard is not recognized. Tampering with the url I can reach the dashboard, but my question here is why I'm being asked for authentication if I'm trying to reach an anonymous authentication enabled dashboard.
I've tried also to pass headers with basic authentication of anonymous user to the request on the proxy adding
RequestHeader set Authorization "Basic encoded64userandpass"

to the Location
When doing this I got an error that states that https://my-kibana-domain/s/my-dashboard-space/bootstrap.js cannot be executed. I've checked that this happens because it arrives with content-type: application/json, instead of content-type: application/javascript.
I've been searching the web trying to solve this for two straight days, and I'm pretty confused at this point.
Can anyone throw some light here?
